# Access another twig template within another

Tags: twig, bolt-cms

I'm working with Bolt CMS and the following and it prints out the file name.

```
{% for image in record.gallery %}
  {{ image.filename }}
{% endfor %}
```

But what I want to do is to render these inside an img tag, and doing so causes a 404 because the images are stored within the files directory.

I've attempted to do the following which according to the Bolt CMS is how you access uploaded files in the files directory:

```
{% for image in record.gallery %}
  {{ asset('image.filename', 'files') }}
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How do I access image.filename within the asset tag?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this myself! Just needed to remove the quotes.

```
{% for image in record.gallery %}
  {{ asset(image.filename, 'files') }}
{% endfor %}
```